# Create Ring/Silent notification view ios13

Tags: ios, notifications, ios13

I'm trying to figure out how to create notification in iOS, like Ring/Silent Notification. Is it any class in UIKit for it?

I would be thankful for any suggestions! Thank you

[Ring/Silent Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU0NK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen that notification in any other occasion than using the physical iPhone switch for silent mode on/off, So I believe there's no native way of doing that.

That's for a good reason, though. Presenting that exact same notification would be very confusing to the user. For example: if the user had silent mode ON, then something in your app would change that to OFF, his iPhone's physical switch would still be ON, causing an inconsistency.

There's probably a way of doing so, using private API or constructing it yourself from scratch, but you really shouldn't do it.

There must be a better way of doing what you want to do by showing this notification.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Ring/Silent notification is just an example. I'm looking for style only. Of course, trigger and text would be different. And it would be inside of the app window.

Comment: @krbiz oh, that's better :) The style looks a bit like what's called a "toast" on android. You might be able to find some libraries for iOS that do something similar. If you don't find any that suits your needs, then I believe doing it from scratch is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create such notification *to use within the app*, you can perfectly create it from scratch. If you're trying to display that notification in iOS (outside the app), no, it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for answer! How to create such notification to use within the app window?

Comment: Well, just like any other view?